# Pagination of results of wp_list_pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm displaying the child pages of a page with this code:

```
<ul class="llista-residus">
    <?php
    global $id;
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li'    => '',
        'child_of'    => $id,
        'show_date'   => 'modified',
        'date_format' => $date_format,
    ) );
    ?>
</ul>
```

I have a lot of results, so I would like to display them in different pages, with an alphabetical pagination. I've tried different solutions but not working (my notions of php are very basic...). Any idea?

Thank you

EDIT:

Finally I tried it modifying this code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38188/pagination-in-a-custom-list-created-with-get-pages-function

The result:

```
<?php
$thispost = $post->ID;
// Posts Per Page option
$ppp = 30;

// find out on which page are we
$paging =  isset( $_GET['list'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['list'] ) ? $_GET['list'] : 1 ;
// arguments for listed pages
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $thispost,
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'paged' => $paging,
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$pages = get_posts( $args );

if ( count( $pages ) > 0 ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $pages as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo '<p>No pages!</p>';
}

$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$thispost);
$count_pages = ceil (count($pages) / $ppp);

// display the navigation
if ( $count_pages > 0 ) {
    echo '<div> Pàg. ';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count_pages; $i++) {
        $separator = ( $i < $count_pages ) ? ' | ' : '';
        $url_args = add_query_arg( 'list', $i );
        echo  "<a href='$url_args'>$i</a>".$separator;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

I don't know if it is the more correct way, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) says that

you can sort your results using `sort_column`.

I didn't see a way to do paging using this function, but luckily you can use [get_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) for this purpose. With `sort_order` you can specify your direction of sorting. `offset` and `number` can be used to have a paging. So, if you read the relevant parts of the links I have provided in this answer, you should be able to solve the issue. If not, then please let me know.

Comment: @asformigas it's basically a functionality which generates a MySQL query based on the parameters it gets and executes it. When the response is returned, the function parses it and returns a result as specified in the docs. You have a control on how it works before you call the function by specifying your parameters for paging and sorting and you have control on what you do with the results.